4-20mA sensor reading
I've designed a schematic for a 4channel 4-20mA input reading circuit utilizing the INA196 IC with an ADS1115 ADC. After simulating the circuit in TINA, it appeared to be functioning correctly. However, upon connecting a 4-20mA sensor to the circuit, I encountered an issue where the ADC consistently outputs 32767, and the other channels yield no readings at all. I'm uncertain about the root cause of this problem. Could someone provide assistance or insights?"

Please measure the voltages the inputs of the ADS1115, confirm the input current, link the datasheets for the two chips used. Let's forget about the ADS1115 configuration (internal PGA) and just look at voltages for now.  Also please confirm the current sensor part number. Your text says INA196 and the schematic says INA195- there is a huge difference in gain. In any case, are you are aware this is a crude part intended for power supply monitoring and thus degrading the performance compared to the ADC by more than two orders of magnitude?

I'm using 4-20mA generator as input to the circuit(https://www.amazon.in/Generator-Adjustable-Simulator-Transmitter-Rechargeable/dp/B09KVLCN6R)

Datasheet link (https://www.digikey.in/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/INA196AIDBVT/66598)
I'm using 4-20mA generator as input to the circuit(https://www.amazon.in/Generator-Adjustable-Simulator-Transmitter-Rechargeable/dp/B09KVLCN6R)
I have set the current to 10.3mA , this current is given as input to Ch1 and the output when measured at INA196 IC is 43mV.
as per the calculation , the INA196 supposed to output 1.03V but it is not happening

It may not be your problem, but you are relatively heavily loading the INA196 output compared to the 100kΩ and 10nF maximum capacitance in the datasheet. Maybe try removing the capacitor on the channel you are testing.

I'll try removing cap and test it , but for my knowledge sake, the simulation outputs required voltage with or without capacitor, based on the simulation I implemented in PCB ,why it is performing differently when on PCB?

Removed the 100nF cap, but now the voltage reduce to 38mV

I read this link (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/332378/measuring-4-20ma-current-using-the-4-20ma-r-click-module/332387#332387), somewhat similar , The circuit I attached in previous post is similar to figure 2 , difference is 24V instead of 16V, I'm also getting 24V between CN1 and CN2 terminals when nothing is connected, does that means only 2 wire sensors has to be connected?

Yes, 2-wire between input and ground.

I got it working, it was my mistake, I didnt connected the sensors properly. anyway thanks for your help
